# Latest effective_start_Date with column null in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `asg_table` with columns `effective_start_date` and `effective_end_date`.

**asg_table**:

```
asg_number     effective_start_date  effective_end_date   location        department        action_code
1                01-jan-2018           20-jan-2018                         HR                 HIRE     
1                21-JAN-2018           18-FEB-2018         Vietnam        HR                 CHANGE_ASG
1                19-FEB-2018           28-feb-2018         Vietnam         Manegment          TERMINATION
1                01-jul-2018           31-Dec-2019                          Payroll            HIRE
1                01-jan-2019            31-dec-4712        Peru              Payroll           CHANGE_ASG
2                01-feb-2019           01-apr-2019                         HR                 HIRE
2                02-APR-2019           31-DEC-4712         Vietnam         Payroll            CHANGE_ASG
```

I want to create a query such that the latest effective_start_date with action_code HIRE comes whose location is null
i.e. in this case asg_number 1 should return  01-jul-2018 as the effective_start_Date where location is null.
in case of asg_number 2 the query should return 01-feb-2019 where location is null

Is there a function to find the latest effective_start_Date ?

I found the last post for first effective_start_Date helpful but this finds the FIRST EFFECTIVE START DATE NOT THE LATEST.

```
Select * from
  (Select t.*, 
  Row_number() over 
  (partition by t.employee_id order by t.effective_start_date) as rn
  From asg_table t
  Where t.location is null 
  AND t.action_code = 'HIRE')
Where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `desc` for the ordering:

```
Select *
from (Select t.*, 
             Row_number() over (partition by t.employee_id order by t.effective_start_date desc) as rn
      From asg_table t
      Where t.location is null and t.action_code = 'HIRE'
     )
Where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Works because `NULL` sorts higher than any non-null value.  I would suggest ordering by `t.effective_start_date DESC NULLS FIRST` just to make that a little more explicit and readable, for junior developers who might not know/remember how nulls sort.

Answer (score 0):

you need order by in decending order

```
   Select * from
      (Select t.*, 
      Row_number() over 
      (partition by t.employee_id order by t.effective_start_date desc) as rn
      From asg_table t
      Where t.location is null 
      AND t.action_code = 'HIRE')
    Where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `asg_number` along with `employee_id` and `order by` must be `desc`

```
Select * from
  (Select t.*, 
  Row_number() over 
  (partition by t.employee_id, t.asg_number order by t.effective_start_date desc) as rn
  From asg_table t
  Where t.location is null 
  AND t.action_code = 'HIRE')
Where rn = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: How is this different from the 2 other answers that were already posted?

Comment: Partition by clause

Comment: @Tejash - can you pls help me out with my latest question ?